# Help me to understand examples

Tags: tense, sentence-meaning

What is the difference between these sentences.Especially,  what does the first example mean?

> 1) I have been there.
>
> 2) I had been there.
>
> 3) I was there.

Comment: more ans  please

Comment: More [details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439), please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should learn the basic grammar of English. It must be mentioned that, you need to provide context for your questions and pinpoint the bottleneck. But, as a learner, I answer this question since it seems to be an exercise! Also,  I strongly recommend you to see StoneyB's priceless post [What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](//ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it).

1. I have been there (Present Perfect)

   This tense is extensively used in English and can be very complicated. This sentence could mean you were there (last year, yesterday or just a minute ago) and you are somewhere else now. However, present perfect tense is usually used to talk about the events that started some time ago and continued up to now. Consider:

   > I have worked in this company since I was 16 years old.
2. I had been there (Past Perfect)

   This tense is used to talk about the events that happened before some other events. Therefore, your second sentence is regularly used in a sentence like:

   > I had been there before the flood ruined the city.
3. I was there (Simple Past)

   It implies a fact in the past which is "you were there". This tense is usually used to talk about the actions finished in the past; an event finished in the past.

   > He played only 5 matches for Manchester United last season. He was not very successful.

Comment: _I have been there_ can also mean "I have experienced that" (as in the idiom "Been there, done that").